# Using Ternary Operator to Handle Three Different Conditions

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm using the ternary operator to handle importing data from SQL to Mongo for a variety of fields. For one particular field it's a little trickier than the others, because I want to handle three different conditions:

- `1` should port to `true`,
- `0` should port to `false`,
- and `null` should port to `null`.

This is what I'm trying:

```
  saved: data.saved && data.saved === 1 ? true : data.saved && data.saved === 0 ? false : null
```

Would this accomplish what I'm needing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a direct check for `null` and if not convert the numerical values to boolean.

```
value === null ? null : Boolean(value)
```

Comment: the last `value` should be `data.saved`: `saved: data.saved === null ? null : Boolean(data.saved)`

Comment: Just realized that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can just coerce the value to boolean:

`saved: (data === null) ? null : !!data`